# Crocodoc api not working with php

Tags: php, api

I am trying to use [Crocodoc api](https://crocodoc.com/docs/api/) with the [following code](https://github.com/prince-mishra/crocodoc-php) to get the status.

```
$croco = new Crocodoc();

$uuids = "786e072b-981c-4d2a-8e80-80e215f1f7c2";
echo "\n\nchecking status of : ", $uuids;
$status = $croco->getStatus($uuids);
echo "\n\nstatus is : ", $status;

class Crocodoc { 
    public $api_key = 'HPUd6LZXg5174TAENbvBcx30';
    public $api_url = 'https://crocodoc.com/api/v2/';

    public function getStatus($uuids){
        $url = $this->api_url.'document/status';
        $token = $this->api_key;
        $dataStr = '?token='.$token.'&uuids='.$uuids;
        // this is a GET request
        $output = $this->doCurlGet($url, $dataStr);
        return $output;
    }
}
```

I don't get the status and no error. What is wrong or it does not work in evaluation mode. Right now I am using it local with XAMPP, can that be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `doCurlGet` does?

Because the [request](http://hurl.it/hurls/4f438998cf5e33cc95032fb03e90bdef93f0b2d6/30a568f1036079e3d8dc07068c2f025809e47d05) (and response) is fine:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.2.0
Date: Thu, 24 May 2012 10:11:27 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive

[
  {
    "uuid": "786e072b-981c-4d2a-8e80-80e215f1f7c2",
    "viewable": true,
    "status": "DONE"
  }
]
```

You might try with a real curl, like:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "/* generated url to crocodoc */");
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Or directly:

```
$data = file_get_contents('/* generated url to crocodoc */');
```

**Edit:**

Just tried [this code](http://codepad.viper-7.com/wt3U3P), and it works fine:

```
$croco  = new Crocodoc();
$uuids  = "786e072b-981c-4d2a-8e80-80e215f1f7c2";
$status = $croco->getStatus($uuids);
var_dump($status);

class Crocodoc { 
    public $api_key = 'HPUd6LZXg5174TAENbvBcx30';
    public $api_url = 'https://crocodoc.com/api/v2/';

    public function getStatus($uuids){
        $url = $this->api_url.'document/status';
        $token = $this->api_key;
        $dataStr = '?token='.$token.'&uuids='.$uuids;

        // this is a GET request
        return file_get_contents($url.$dataStr);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code is from here: https://github.com/prince-mishra/crocodoc-php and you can find doCurlGet in index.php

Comment: I see, did you try with the last example I gave you?

Comment: Thanks but I added this [code]curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);[/code] in doCurlGet and now its working. Guess its ssl problem ;-)

Comment: @Xtreme can you please answer to your own question to clarify what you did to resolve the problem? you would then be able to "close your question" by marking your answer as valid.